# When was the original Double Slit Experiment (by Thomas Young) conducted?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, history

Is there a published date, or is only the year (1801) known?

Comment: Better asked at History of Science & Mathematics? https://hsm.stackexchange.com where there is an answer https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2629/how-did-young-perform-his-double-slit-experiment

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about historic dates rather than actual physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Thomas Young, speaking on 24 November 1803, to the Royal Society of London, began his description of the historic experiment. His talk was published in the following year's Philosophical Transactions, and was destined to become a classic, still reprinted and read today."

[Thomas Young](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Young_(scientist))

[Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society. 94: 1–16.](https://books.google.com/books?id=7AZGAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q&f=false)

"Strictly speaking, there was no double slit in the original experiment as described by Young. Instead, the sunlight reflected off a steering mirror passed through a small hole in a paper, and the resulting thin light beam was then split in half alongside a paper card."

[Young's interference experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_interference_experiment)